# Docker compose links - get real IP

Tags: docker, hyperlink, docker-compose

I have a problem with use of external_links.

In my configuration I have (docker-compose)  :

```
web: 
   external_links: 
      - s3server:s3server
```

I can `ping s3server:8000` from "web" container, but server itself has hard time to resolve s3server (give Error Response). When I do `curl 172.xx.xx.xx:8000` from "web" container then it's working fine.

How to resolve s3server:8000 to 172.xx.xx.xx:8000 ?

**Error Response**: `curl http://s3server:8000/`

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidURI</Code><Message>Couldn't parse the specified URI.</Message><Resource></Resource><RequestId>14b58fb57f4faf412b84</RequestId></Error>root@c99e08f41384:/#
```

**Success Response**: `curl http://172.23.0.2:8000/`

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><Resource></Resource><RequestId>2e3d48dbc34ab5456c22</RequestId></Error>
```

Comment: What is the error that you get ?

Comment: .. really no one?